# Checking server response Periodically

Tags: android

I am making an app where a user is Register and Login. After Signin user status is send to server as online through JSON as I am using mysql database. now admin want's to send some data or alert to online user, which approach i should apply to android side to check continuously server response. when this response came new activity have to start and admin can send response any time.
I make a service approach to check server response after 1 sec using AlarmManager, it's not good approach as it makes my app and also mobile slow continuously service creating.
suggest me what approach i should make to check continuously server response.  someone told me to use Google Cloud Messaging approach(how response can be sent to a specific user?) but i need suggestion or any other best approach

Comment: Use push messages instead.

Comment: can you send me any link on push message explanation

Comment: I think best option for your requirement is GCM. And GCM also can send response to specific user by him/her regId.

Comment: to specific user by his regId you mean device id or Login id given it in database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use Google Cloud Messaging.
First of all When the user first installs the App. below can be the algorithm to apply

- User attempts Log in
- Check if the device has been registered -(this is done by checking the sharedPreference you   initially would have saved the regID in)
- if device hasn't been registered
- Register the device with GCM
- GCM returns a regID (a very long character)
- save the regID to your server for the user logged on
- save the regID to a sharedPreference
- proceed with log-in in the user

From your server you can send a info to Your device

- Send a message to GCM and the regID
- GCM identifies the regID and locate the device.
- GCM broadcast the message to the device if online or waits till when the device comes online
- your device should get the message from GCM (The message can be a action_key that defines what you intend , e.g PICK_UP might mean : "hey the server needs you to pick up some info")
- so if message equals PICK_UP, do something e.g connect to the server and pick what's needed
- You shouldn't send large data from your server to GCM

Using GCM will save you from periodically requesting for info from the server.
It also will save your users from wasting so much bandwidth unnecessarily.

I hope it helps.